# XAML: Combobox selection triggers another combobox

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, combobox, textbox

I try in XAML to trigger a combobox(cb2) and a textbox(textbox) trough another combobox(cb1) selection. The textbox is no problem but i got problems with the combobox. Do you guys have a solution for my problem?

```
    <ComboBox x:Name="cb1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Margin="37,212,0,0">
        <ComboBoxItem Content="1"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="2"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="3"/>
    </ComboBox>
    <ComboBox x:Name="cb2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Margin="234,212,0,0">
        <ComboBoxItem Content="a"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="b"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="c"/>
    </ComboBox>
    <TextBox x:Name="textbox"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" MaxLength="15" Width="120" Margin="234,101,0,0" Height="22">
        <TextBox.Style>
            <Style>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=cb1, Path=SelectedValue.Content}" Value="1">
                        <Setter Property="TextBox.Text" Value="test" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=cb1, Path=SelectedValue.Content}" Value="2">
                        <Setter Property="TextBox.Text" Value="test2" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TextBox.Style>
    </TextBox>
```

Too much to write it down

Answer (score 0):

Answer to my Question:

```
<ComboBox.Style>
    <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=cb1, Path=SelectedValue.Content}" Value="1">
                <Setter Property="SelectedIndex" Value="2" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ComboBox.Style>
```